# Can I start a game on PC and transfer that game to Android for the game "A Dark Room"?

Tags: a-dark-room, mobile

In the game "A Dark Room", I have made good progress on a public computer, but now I would like to continue the game on my Android.

I've downloaded the app, and a new game started automatically. I can't find anything like a menu or anything that gives options to save/load a game.

Is it possible to transfer a game from PC to Android in the game "A Dark Room"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android and iOS versions of A Dark Room are created in a different framework and by a different creator than the browser version. Currently, it does not seem like these versions have cross-platform save compatibility.

Source: http://blog.doublespeakgames.com/news/a-dark-room-save-management/#comment-36173 and http://blog.doublespeakgames.com/news/a-dark-room-save-management/#comment-314408